# Error in opencv using qt in imread function (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, qt-creator

My problem is that i have just install *qtcreator* and opencv. I try to make simple opencv application to read an image but i am stuck with below error; any one can help please,

error:

> undefined reference to
>   `QFutureInterfaceBase::setThreadPool(QThreadPool*)'

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("/home/abdallah/Desktop/image.jpg");
cv::imshow("Display Image",inputImage);
cv::waitKey(0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

project.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-03-15T18:52:15
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui



SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /home/hend/opencv249/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_ml
LIBS += -lopencv_video
LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d
LIBS += -lopencv_objdetect
LIBS += -lopencv_contrib
LIBS += -lopencv_legacy
LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

Please if any one can help or some thing not clear tell me to discuss it..

Comment: I just tried it with opencv 3.4.1 and it works correctly, is that all your code?, although I recommend not using waitkey() since it is blocking and you will have problems with the GUI.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: i am using Qt version 5.3

Comment: yes this is only my code and i try to search this error but nothing..